# Oracle jobs repeat interval

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a job made with oracle sqldeveloper; I made a program executing a stored procedure that inserts a record every 20 seconds

this is how my job looks like (from the DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS table)

```
OWNER: MYSCHEME
JOB_NAME: DUMMY_ORACLE_JOB
JOB_SUBNAME: 
JOB_CREATOR: MYSCHEME
PROGRAM_OWNER: MYSCHEME
PROGRAM_NAME: DUMMY_ORACLE_PROGRAM
SCHEDULE_TYPE: CALENDAR
START_DATE: 30/07/13 12:51:36,747000000 AMERICA/CARACAS
REPEAT_INTERVAL: FREQ=SECONDLY;BYSECOND=2
EVENT_QUEUE_OWNER: 
EVENT_QUEUE_NAME: 
JOB_CLASS: DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS
ENABLED: TRUE
AUTO_DROP: TRUE
RESTARTABLE: FALSE
STATE: SCHEDULED
JOB_PRIORITY: 3
RUN_COUNT: 32
FAILURE_COUNT: 0
RETRY_COUNT: 0
LAST_START_DATE: 30/07/13 14:06:02,104000000 AMERICA/CARACAS
LAST_RUN_DURATION: 0 0:0:0.16000000
NEXT_RUN_DATE: 30/07/13 14:07:02,000000000 AMERICA/CARACAS
SCHEDULE_LIMIT:
```

As you can see my repeat interval is set every 2 seconds, but the rows appear every minute:

[image]

Am I missing something? how can I set the interval every 2 seconds?

btw this is just a test job, I want to understand the interval logic

Comment: untested, but try: FREQ=SECONDLY; INTERVAL=2;  Also see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#ARPLS138)